# How can I access res/colors.xml from other .xml files in Android?

Tags: android, xml, resources

I have the following color under res/values/colors.xml:

```
 <resources>
  <color name="unpaidwarning">#942626</color>
 </resources>
```

I have created a style and I am trying to access **unpaidwarning** from it:

```
 <item name="android:textColor">???????</item>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access colors.xml in that line, where the interrogation marks stand.

Comment: use `@color/unpaidwarning`

Comment: Thanks! I tried it before and for some reason it didn't work. Thank you. :)

Comment: By Using this android:textColor="@color/unpaidwarning" what error you are getting?

Comment: Are there errors in your project? New resources declared won't show up unless you are able to run a gradle build can generate new code. If there are errors in your project, the build fails and there is no generated code, hence the resource assignment doesn't work.

Comment: can you post the full code of the file which has the line <item name="android:textColor">???????</item>

Answer (score 2):

when you created a project there's a predefined color.xml in res/values/. In the colors.xml there're:

```
<resources>
    <!--<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>-->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#23DEBF</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

It is used in styles.xml, which is in the same directory.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

You just use `@color/you_defined_color`. That's OK.